# What are the benefits of IntegerCache while using Integer?

Tags: java, integer

In `Integer class`, there is `private static class IntegerCache`.

What is the use of this class?

What are the benefits of it while using `Integer`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Values between -128 and 127 are cached for reuse. This is an example of the [*flyweight* pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), which minimizes memory usage by reusing immutable objects.

---

Beyond being an optimization, this behaviour is part of the JLS, so the following may be relied upon:

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 1;
Integer c = 999;
Integer d = 999;
System.out.println(a == b); // true
System.out.println(c == d); // false
```

Answer (score 5):

IntegerCache caches value between -128 to +127 to optimise Autoboxing.

You can set upper bound greater than `127` using `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=NEWVALUE` or `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=NEWVALUE`

Answer (score 3):

Look at its implementation:

```
private static class IntegerCache {
   static final int high;
   static final Integer cache[];
   static {
      final int low = -128;
      int h = 127;
      if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
          int i = Long.decode(integerCacheHighPropValue).intValue();
          i = Math.max(i, 127);
          h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - -low);
      }
      high = h;
      cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
      int j = low;
      for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
      cache[k] = new Integer(j++);
   }
   private IntegerCache() {}
}
```

256 values are cached to be used again, they'll be loaded when you create the first `Integer` object.

So when you use the `==` operator to check the equality for two `Integer`s on the range of [-127,128], you'll get it as if you where comparing two `int`s. But if you compare two `Integer`s out of this range using `==`, you'll get `false`, even if they have the same value.